# annualized value in percent and absolut

Tags: economics, percentages

I have two values which represents the profit and loss (PnL) calculated within a **time period**:

- `pnlAbsolute` = 7$ (within 5 days)
- `pnlPercent` = 0.2% (within 8 days)

Now, I want to calculate its **annualized** version:

**Calculate annualized pnlAbsolute (annualized income):**

```
annualizedPnlAbsolute = 7$ * (365days / 5days) = 511$
```

**Calculate annualized pnlPercent (annualized return):**

```
annualizedPnlPercent = (1 + 0.2%/100) pow (365days / 8days) - 1 = 0.0954 = 9,54%
```

Both formulas are correct, however which one is more accurate? I guess, `annualiedPnlAbsolute` is a rougher estimate than  `annualizedPnlPercent`. Am I right?

**EDIT:**

The main aim I want to achieve by annualizing is, to compare multiple annualized values. I must annualize it because the values can be in different time periods. For example, I have `pnlAbsolute1` (or `pnlRelative1`) achieved in *3 days*, `pnlAbsolute2` (or `pnlRelative2`) achieved in *5 days*, etc. The main question is: Is it better to compare by `annualizedPnlAbsolute` or compare by `annualizedPnlRelative`.

Which annualized version is more suitable for **comparisons** - the `annualizedPnlAbsolute` or the `annualizedPnlRelative`?

Comment: "accurate" isn't well defined here.  If you are getting a fixed income, then an additive return is more accurate.  If you are looking at compound interest with a known interest rate, then the compounding formula is better.  Context matters.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the hint. I edited my question, so it's more clear what I want to ask.

Comment: But, again, all this depends on how you are modeling returns.  If you imagine that you can re-invest earnings at an equivalent yield, then some sort of compounding is warranted.  But...well, why not just compare the numbers as they stand?  Where is the advantage in modeling an annualized version?

Comment: @lulu I edited my question again, so it's even more clear what I want to ask.

Comment: I feel like I am just repeating myself.  It all depends on how you model the returns. If you are broke, and then get a job where someone gives you $\$1000$ a week, you really have to use the additive return.  Saying it was an infinite yield is entirely misleading.  If you are looking at a stock you can annualize the return but...well, if the stock goes up $2\%$ in a day would you really want to say that that was a $13000\%$ annualized return (or whatever it works out to)?

Comment: Should say:  in practice, it's common for people looking at volatile assets to divide the return by the standard deviation of the returns.  That helps to normalize things.  But, again, it all depends on modeling and how you intend to use the numbers you get.

Comment: I want to have a performance summary (benchmark) where I can say that `annualizedValue1` is better than `annualizedValue2` and the question I have is, should I use the percentage version or not. It's a one time lookup of these values and I must decide which annualizedValue is the best.

Comment: Well, I won't repeat myself again, I'll just give you an example:  suppose you  are comparing two assets.  One is a stock you have purchased with cash and the other is the same stock you purchased on margin (say you put down $50\%$ at $0$ riskless rate).  The second asset has twice the return of the first (annualized or otherwise) yet it would be foolish to declare that this made it a better investment.  Context matters.

Comment: I think, I understand. The "annualized income" does **not** involve *the geometrical increase* (which is calculated by the "annualized return"). Therefore, in my case, I should take the "annualized income" to compare different values.

Comment: I think I've said quite clearly that there is no one-size-fits-all measure for the return which applies here. It all depends on the assets involved and on how you intend to use whatever metric you use.  Portfolio managers spend a lot of energy analyzing sand comparing assets for this reason